# Is SAPJCo specific to a SAP installation or can be reused between different SAP Boxes?

Tags: sapjco3

I'm trying to connect to a SAP system using SAP JCo. Our client is taking long time to download and give the SAP JCo. Is SAP JCo dll and Jar specific to a SAP Box or can be used across different boxes? Can I use a SAP JCo downloaded using  SAP ID registered in our SAP Box and use it?

Comment: Have a look over at Server Fault or Super User, they both cover SAP related questions. Here on Stackoverflow are only software development related questions and a low probability of being helped on that one.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the redistribution of the connector is not allowed by SAP.
-> if you develop an application for a customer, this customer has to download and provide you the JCO lib for his SAP installation.
See : https://support.sap.com/en/product/connectors.html

Answer (score 0):

SAP JCo is library which can be used to communicate with any SAP on-premise system that supports SAP's RFC protocol. This is comparable to a database vendor specific JDBC driver.
Just provide the logon credentials and connect to any available system of this type.

You can find further general information about the SAP Java Connector here:
https://support.sap.com/jco

Answer (score 0):

*(Much appreciate trixx's suggestion in the comments; I am editing this reply to directly answer op's question instead of giving general statement)*

SAPJco is not specific to an SAP installation. Assume you have a valid S-ID to access SAP software download page ("Connector" section) to download the JCO file. Once you download it, you can start with some simple examples. [Here is one blog for reference](https://goenning.net/2014/06/13/connecting-the-world-to-sap-with-rfc/).

*(original reply was:
Your best bet would be to search in Google through keywords like "SAP JCO sample" to read some very basic examples, and try to practice from them. Once you start to get used to the design pattern, you can blend your requirement in and become productive. It is not difficult to get started. Keep learning and practicing. )*

Comment: Many examples found in the web are outdated and still deal with the deprecated and incompatible JCo2 API. One should not learn this old stuff anymore. Especially for a JCo beginner this could be rather confusing than being helpful. If you have tips which JCo3 examples are wortth to study you should give concrete links. Nevertheless I did not downvote your answer. Keep on helping. :)